# What is Himeka Akishino's relation to Eita in Oreshura?

Tags: oreshura

It was stated that she was Eita's lover from his "past life". But how is she related to Eita? Was she a childhood friend or an old classmate of Eita from the preschool?

Answer (score 1):

I've only watched the anime, but it's very clear that Himeka is delusional. She calls herself the "Burning Princess Saint Dragon Lady of Dawn"... and she came up with the story of Eita and her being lovers in a past life herself. It's obviously just a fabrication that she uses to support her advances on Eita.